# Caliburn Micro Attach Event called multiple times

Tags: mvvm, xamarin, xamarin.forms, caliburn.micro

I want to call a method in the view (ContentPage - Xamarin.Forms)  "Appearing" event. I have done something like the following

```
cm:Message.Attach="[Event Appearing] = [Action SayHello()]"
```

SayHello is a method in my ViewModel. However, I see that this method keeps on getting called twice. Wondering what is making that happen. Any ideas what I might be missing?

The interesting thing here is the call stack in there. Seems to be getting called from another place the second time. Does this mean that the Appearing Event gets fired from multiple locations?

**Call Stack the first time**
[image]

**Call Stack the second time**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `OnAppearing` method and also `OnDisappearing` are not called consistently when using current versions of Xamarin.Forms (right now, that's be v2.2 or v2.3).

- For every call to `OnAppearing` you should see a balanced call to `OnDisappearing`
- If you have a tab based environment you might see multiple calls.
- You might be able to work around it.
- What you observe might be a bug in Forms.

If you think you see a bug and the calls are nothing that are caused by your app, please submit a bug report at [Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/newbug). Please include a self contained example.